# ASP.NET MVC Delete Action Link with confirm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
      <td>
  <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteUser", new RouteValueDictionary(new {uname=item.UserName}), new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this User?');" }) %>
    </td>
```

In Global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "DeleteUser",
               "Account.aspx/DeleteUser/{uname}",
               new { controller = "Account", action = "DeleteUser", uname = "" }
           );
```

In ActionContorller.cs

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser(string uname)
{
   //delete user
}
```

the value of  uname in the controller is being passed is empty string("").

Comment: Account.aspx? Dude, this isn't Web Forms. The tutorials on ASP.NET/mvc are excellent: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Comment: In some settings (I.e. working with IIS 6) using .aspx can be acceptable to help IIS figure out routing to the controllers (see http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) - especially when you don't have access to configure IIS.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "DeleteUser", 
    "Account",
    new { 
        uname = item.UserName 
    }, 
    new { 
        onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this User?');" 
    }
) %>
```

Then make sure that the generated link is correct:

```
<a href="/Account.aspx/DeleteUser/foo" onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this User?&#39;);">Delete</a>
```

Also note that using a plain GET verb for an action that modifies the state on the server is not recommended.

Here's what I would recommend you:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(string uname)
{
   //delete user
}
```

and in the view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(
    "DeleteUser", 
    "Account", 
    new { uname = item.UserName }, 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { id = "myform" })
) { %>
    <%= Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
<% } %>
```

and in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this User?');
    });
});
```

You might also consider adding an [anti forgery token](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/29/AntiForgeryTokenInMVCFramework.aspx) to protect this action against [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: I tried copying this example, I have a Controller named CalendarController, a view named Calendar, and a separate action called DeleteTraffic, I used the BeginForm example you have there, but whenever I click the delete button the Calendar() action is called, not the DeleteTraffic(). your example, is the view called DeleteUser? how do I make a submit call another action than the action connected to the view?